# How do I assert a temporary text on a page in Cypress?

Tags: automation, cypress

When I click a button, a text appears for about a second and then disappears. How Do I capture that text and assert it?

Comment: Have you tried to do a simple `cy.get("yourElement").should("have.text", "expectedText")`? If so, what happens? Please let us know what you've tried so far and we can better assist you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Look true your app code or ask your developers to put a distinct selector and look it like.:

```
cy.get("yourElement").should("not.exist")
//action to make it appear
cy.get("yourElement").should("have.text", "expectedText")
```